# Binary XML file line : Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, performance

> ```
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> android:orientation="vertical"
> tools:context="com.netvariant.nissan_survey.MainActivity" >
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="244dp"
>         android:layout_height="70dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
>         android:src="@drawable/header_feedback" >
>     </ImageView>
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="244dp"
>         android:layout_height="70dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
>         android:src="@drawable/logo" >
>     </ImageView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:src="@drawable/header_arrow" >
>     </ImageView>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:orientation="vertical"
>         android:paddingBottom="40dp" >
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="230dp"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:singleLine="false"
>             android:text="@string/choose"
>             android:textSize="24sp" />
>         <FrameLayout
>             android:layout_width="250dp"
>             android:layout_height="250dp"
>             android:layout_gravity="center"
>             android:background="@android:color/white"
>             android:gravity="center"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>             <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                 android:id="@+id/cv"
>                 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>                 android:layout_width="200dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:paddingLeft="25dp"
>                 android:background="@android:color/black"
>                 android:paddingRight="25dp"
>                 android:paddingTop="25dp" >
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:text="@string/arabic"
>                     android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
>                 </TextView>
>             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>               <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                 android:id="@+id/cv1"
>                 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>                 android:layout_width="200dp"
>                 android:background="@android:color/black"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:paddingLeft="25dp"
>                 android:paddingRight="25dp"
>                 android:paddingTop="25dp" >
>                 <TextView
>                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:text="@string/english"
>                     android:textColor="@android:color/white" >
>                 </TextView>
>             </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
>         </FrameLayout>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Whats wrong with my code? Why I get such error on card view, which is line 71. I still cannot find a solution, while i implement same as tutorials.
Please help if possible. i added some properties, removed some.no influence and same error over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added the CardView dependency in your module's `build.gradle` file? Make sure you have it because it's the same exception you get when you forget including it.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Answer (score 1):

In React-native you need to force the same version for appcompat in your gradle.build,

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    }
}
```